# Binding ViewModel field outside of Item Source

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I have an ItemSource which binds a list of contact

```
<ListView  x:Name="contactsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding contacts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Should be to my View Model instead of Contacts}"></Image>
                            <Label Text="{Binding FullName}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

the Full Name binding works fine. My problem is the Image Source is not included in the Contact model so I need to retrieve that from my view Model How can I do it?

**VIEW MODEL**

```
    public class ContactsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    private string _contactImage;

    public string ContactImage
    {
        get => _contactImage; set
        {
            _contactImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ContactImage");
        }
    }

    public ContactsViewModel(List<Contact> _contacts)
    {
        contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(_contacts);
        ContactImage = "arrow.png";



    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**CODE BEHIND VIEW**

```
    public partial class ContactListPage : TabbedPage
{
    public ContactsViewModel vm;
    public ContactListPage (List<Contact> _contacts)
    {
        vm = new ContactsViewModel(_contacts);
        BindingContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the scope within a `ListView` item is different than a level higher. To overcome this, create a reference to a parent control. I see you already named your `ListView`, so we can use that.

Do it like this: `<Image Source="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ContactImage, Source={x:Reference contactsListView}}"></Image>`